# Dynamic stored procedure returns rows in SSMS but not in code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a situation where I need to be able to return a variable number of columns with variable column names. I have created a Stored Procedure that works in SSMS but only returns a zero when I execute it from code.
Here is the Stored Procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uSp_CR_ComplianceList] 
@UserID VARCHAR(30),
@OwnRecords VARCHAR(2),
@BusinessUnitTitle VARCHAR(80),
@showComplianceRisk VARCHAR(5),
@useComplianceTitle VARCHAR(5),
@Consequences VARCHAR(50),
@Likelihood VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @custom CURSOR
SET @custom = CURSOR FOR SELECT tblCustomFields.fieldName, tblCustomFields.rptSeq FROM dbo.tblCustomFields WHERE relatedTo = 'CP'
DECLARE @fieldName VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @rptSeq VARCHAR(3)
SET @SQL = 'Select tblProcess.id, tblProcess.ProcessNumber, '
IF @useComplianceTitle = 'True'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'tblProcess.title AS [Title],'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' tblProcess.Process AS [Description], '
IF @showComplianceRisk = 'True' 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'tblProcess.Risk, tblProcess.MRR AS [Risk Rating],'
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'tblConsequences.Comment AS [' + @Consequences + '], tblLikelihood.Title AS [' + @Likelihood + '], tblBusiness.Activity AS [' + @BusinessUnitTitle + '],
   tblProcessCategory.Category, p.Title AS [Responsible Officer], dbo.actionedBy_Positions(tblProcess.id, ''P'') AS [Actioned By],
   rs.statusDescription AS [Status], dbo.Selected_Tag_List(tblProcess.linkedTags) AS Tags'
OPEN @custom
FETCH NEXT FROM @custom INTO @fieldName, @rptSeq
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ', dbo.Get_Custom_Field_Value_Compliance(' + @rptSeq + ',tblProcess.id) AS [' + @fieldName + ']'
    FETCH NEXT FROM @custom INTO @fieldName, @rptSeq
END
CLOSE @custom
DEALLOCATE @custom
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'FROM tblProcess
CROSS JOIN dbo.Security_Compliance_Record_List(' + @UserID + ', ' + @OwnRecords + ', 0) AS p1
     INNER JOIN
     tblBusiness ON tblProcess.BusinessActivity = tblBusiness.id INNER JOIN
     tblProcessCategory ON tblProcess.Category = tblProcessCategory.id INNER JOIN       
    tblPeople p ON tblProcess.Responsibility = p.id INNER JOIN
    tblConsequences ON tblProcess.Consequences = tblConsequences.Consequence INNER JOIN
    tblLikelihood ON tblProcess.Likelihood = tblLikelihood.Likelihood INNER JOIN       
     tblRecordStatus rs ON tblProcess.recordStatus = rs.id INNER JOIN
     tblRiskMatrixNames ON tblProcess.MRR = tblRiskMatrixNames.displayName
WHERE (tblProcess.id = p1.id) ORDER BY tblProcess.ProcessNumber'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

I have tried two different methods to execute the Stored Procedure but they both just return a zero.
The application is in VB and we use LINQ for our data access.
First example using LINQ:

```
    Dim ldb As CaRMSDataContext
ldb = New CaRMSDataContext(sessionHandler.connection.ToString)        
Dim ls = ldb.uSp_CR_ComplianceList("1", "0", sessionHandler.BusinessUnitTitle, "True", "True", sessionHandler.consequencesText, sessionHandler.likelihoodText)
```

The second example is adding a datasource to a DevExpress control. The DevExpress control is not relative to my problem as other Stored Procedures that are not dynamic work perfectly.

```
        Dim connectionParameters As New MsSqlConnectionParameters(sessionHandler.DBServer, sessionHandler.Catalog, sessionHandler.DBUser, sessionHandler.DBPassword, MsSqlAuthorizationType.SqlServer)
    Dim ds As New DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlDataSource(connectionParameters)
    Dim spParameters As New List(Of QueryParameter)(New QueryParameter() {New QueryParameter() With {.Name = "@UserID", .Type = Type.[GetType]("System.String"), .Value = sessionHandler.personID},
                                                    New QueryParameter() With {.Name = "@OwnRecords", .Type = Type.[GetType]("System.String"), .Value = seeOwn},
                                                    New QueryParameter() With {.Name = "@BusinessUnitTitle", .Type = Type.GetType("System.String"), .Value = sessionHandler.BusinessUnitTitle},
                                                    New QueryParameter() With {.Name = "@showComplianceRisk", .Type = Type.GetType("System.String"), .Value = sessionHandler.showComplianceRisk.ToString},
                                                    New QueryParameter() With {.Name = "@useComplianceTitle", .Type = Type.GetType("System.String"), .Value = sessionHandler.useComplianceTitle.ToString},
                                                    New QueryParameter() With {.Name = "@Consequences", .Type = Type.GetType("System.String"), .Value = sessionHandler.consequencesText},
                                                    New QueryParameter() With {.Name = "@Likelihood", .Type = Type.GetType("System.String"), .Value = sessionHandler.likelihoodText}})
    Dim compliance As New StoredProcQuery("Compliance", "uSp_CR_ComplianceList", spParameters)
```

Here is a screen shot of the Stored Procedure executed in SSMS:
[SSMS example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wJYY.png)
Can anybody advise how to get the data to return in code.

Thanks
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about executing the sp from command object and assigning the result to a dataset? What does it return?

```
Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("<your connection string>")
        Dim command As SqlClient.SqlCommand
        command = connection.CreateCommand
        With command
            .CommandText = "uSp_CR_ComplianceList"
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            With .Parameters
                '   add your parameters here
            End With
            Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command)
            Dim dataset As New DataSet
            adapter.Fill(dataset)
        End With
    End Using
```